# How can I handle with json file with null attributs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I need to read a json file and print the data on a table
The json file has a lot of objects, and objects inside objects, arrays...

Example of the json file

```
[
  {
    "id_transaction": 116,
    "company": "ABC",
    "verified": true,
    "date": "2019-04-09T13:31:20.429Z",
    "bio_data": {
      "id": "string",
      "data": "string",
      "digital": [
        {
          "name": "value1",
          "digital": ""
        },
        {
          "name": "value2",
          "digital": "value2"
        },
        {
          "name": "",
          "digital": "value3"
        }       
      ]
    },
    "info_data": {
      "value1": "value1",
      "value2": "",
      "value3": "",
      "value4": "value4",
      "value5": 1.0,
      "value6": ""      
    }
  }
]
```

Any data of this json file can be null, the objects `bio_data` and `info_data` can be null, the array `digital` can be null, and the others simple atributs (`company`, `date` etc..) can be null.

What's the best way to deal with null values? 
For now, I was dealing with each case, changing the null value to `-`, but that's not the most intelligent way. Follow an example:

```
id_transaction !== null ? id_transaction : ' - '
info_data !== null ? info_data.value1 : ' - '
bio_data.digital[0] !== undefined ? bio_data.digital[0].name] : '-'
```

How can I create a fucntion to deal with it? 
Or exists a better way to deal with it (i'm using react)?

Comment: This is not valid JSON - `"value4": boolean` would not parse.

Comment: Why do you need to deal with it? If you're just printing it to a table why does it matter if it is an empty value? Just display it as an empty value then?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I need to change the values because those values are sensitive, that's why json example was wrong

Comment: @S_A what' wrong with be null? There is totally right to use null if it's null..

Comment: A simpler way of writing `id_transaction !== null ? id_transaction : ' - '` is `id_transaction || ' - '` if you don't mind other falsy values like empty strings and 0 also being potentially changed

Comment: the problem is this, supose that I want to access this attribute: `bio_data.digital[0].name`, if digital is null, I got an error

Comment: If you are using `JSON.parse` you can also use a second "[`reviver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter)" parameter letting you transform your data. You can change all the nulls to `' - '` using `JSON.parse('{ "a": null }', (key, value) => value === null ? ' - ' : value)`

Comment: Not getting any exception.. https://jsfiddle.net/d34m758r/ 
Show us the code that is doing the exception

Comment: @William if `"digital": []`, I got the error `TypeError: data.bio_data.digital[0] is undefined`

Comment: @S_A If print normally you wont get any error, if you try to assign to something, there you will get an error. Just try catch around. [https://jsfiddle.net/d34m758r/](https://jsfiddle.net/d34m758r/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what *should* your application do when any of the properties are null? Should it:

- skip that property?
- use a default value such as `'-'`?
- throw an exception?

You'll need to specify that yourself, there is no standard answer.

Once you have specified that, you can use the and- and or-operators (`&&` and `||`) to shorten your code a bit. For example:

```
let name = bio_data.digital && bio_data.digital[0] && bio_data.digital[0].name || 'Unknown';
```

See also:

- [Is there a "null coalescing" operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476436/is-there-a-null-coalescing-operator-in-javascript)
- [Null coalescing operator Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736719/null-coalescing-operator-javascript)